# Counter based in text of table cells

Tags: jquery, counter

I have a table refreshed by Ajax and recieves different values in some cells. I want to do a counter if some values coincide. I have a function that does it but the counter doesn't show the new value until I refresh the entire page. What can I do? I appreciate your help and time guys.

This is my function:

```
var consCount = 0;
$(function() {
$("#pizarra #trPizarra").each(function(){
    var estado = $(this).find('#tdEdo').text();
    var asunto = $(this).find('#tdImg').text();
    var juntos = estado + asunto;

    if(juntos === "listo" + "0" || juntos === "listo" + "4"){ ++consCount; }
});

setInterval(function(){    
$('#count-consulta-span').load(document.URL +  ' #count-consulta-span',function(){
    $('#count-consulta-span').text(consCount);
        });
},3500);
});
```

Comment: Your first `.each()`  jquery function should be in the `setInterval()` function.

Comment: I tried but nothing

Comment: are estado and asunto numbers/strings...add your markup

Comment: If you have a request Ajax updating the table, you should probably update your count in the callback of the request.

Comment: Yes, estado and asunto are strings.. The counter works, but only when refresh all page change the value.

Comment: I honestly do not understand. The span is refresh but the value of counter stay until refresh all page.